# Data structure linked arrays

Tags: java, linked-list

This is a hyperid implementation of a linked list and `ArrayList`:

[image: scheme of the linked arrays]

The total capacity is divided into \$\sqrt{n} \text{ "arrays count"} \sqrt{n} \text{ "array size"}\$. This will lead to, as I assume, \$O(\sqrt{n})\$ for operations like indexing, insertion and deletion, along with \$O(1)\$ for adding

We start with one array and when it become filled we create another one calculating its size based on the value of the current capacity of the `LinkedArrays` \$\sqrt{\text{current capacity}}\$ when the full capacity is reached we increase it

Performance test time in nano seconds for 10000 operations:

> ```
> Testing linked arrays...................testing ArrayList.................testing linked list
>
> Time of adding is 349735................time of adding is 264192..........time of adding is 348790
>
> Time of inserting is 60478240...........time of inserting is 840246516....time of inserting is 161743668
>
> Time of delete is 54515250..............time of delete is 593944378.......time of delete is 264977066  
>
> Time of indexing is 510897..............time of indexing is 445676........time of indexing is 281091364   
>
> Time of search is 373683352.............time of search is 306989747.......time of search is 2512449873
> ```

The `ArrayNode` class:

```java
/* 
 * Copyright (C) 2016 Ahmed Mazher <ahmzel2012@gmail.com>
 *
 * This file "ArrayNode" is part of ahmed.library.
 * ahmed.library is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * ahmed.library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 * along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 */
package ahmed.lib.utilities.datastructure;

/**
 *
 * @author Ahmed Mazher
 */
class ArrayNode {

    ArrayNode prevArr; // pointer to previous array in list of arrays
    ArrayNode nextArr; // it point to next array
    Object[] elements; // the array of elements
    int firstEmptyIndex; // index of empty space for inserting new element at head
    int lastEmptyIndex; //index of empty space for inserting new element at tail
    int count; // numer of elements in array block
    int reservedSpace; //reserved for insertion operation

    ArrayNode(int size) {
        reservedSpace = (int) Math.sqrt(size);
        elements = new Object[size + reservedSpace];
        count = 0;
        prevArr = null;
        nextArr = null;
    }

    ArrayNode withPrev(ArrayNode prev) {
        prevArr = prev;
        return this;
    }

    ArrayNode withNext(ArrayNode next) {
        nextArr = next;
        return this;
    }

    ArrayNode asHead() {
        firstEmptyIndex = elements.length - 1;
        lastEmptyIndex = elements.length;
        return this;
    }

    ArrayNode asTail() {
        firstEmptyIndex = -1;
        lastEmptyIndex = 0;
        return this;
    }

    void expandTail() {
        reservedSpace = (int) Math.sqrt(elements.length);
        Object[] temp = new Object[elements.length + reservedSpace];
        System.arraycopy(elements, firstEmptyIndex + 1, temp, firstEmptyIndex + 1, count);
        elements = temp;
    }

    void expandHead() {
        reservedSpace = (int) Math.sqrt(elements.length);
        Object[] temp = new Object[elements.length + reservedSpace];
        System.arraycopy(elements, 0, temp, reservedSpace, count);
        elements = temp;
    }

}
```

This is a part of the `LinkedArrays` class:

```java
/* 
 * Copyright (C) 2016 Ahmed Mazher <ahmzel2012@gmail.com>
 *
 * This file "LinkedArrays" is part of ahmed.library.
 * ahmed.library is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * ahmed.library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 * along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 */
package ahmed.lib.utilities.datastructure;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;

/**
 * @author Ahmed Mazher
 * @param <E>
 *
 */
public class LinkedArrays<E> implements Collection<E> {

    int minCapacity;//the minimum capacity of data structure
    int currCapacity;//the current currCapacity of data structure
    int eleCount; // total number of elements currently stored
    int arrCount;//current number of arrays
    int maxArraySize;//maximum allowed size of array
    ArrayNode head;//point to the head array
    ArrayNode tail; //point to the tail array

    public LinkedArrays() {
        this(100);
    }

    public LinkedArrays(int capacity) {
        minCapacity = capacity;
        currCapacity = capacity;
        maxArraySize = (int) Math.sqrt(capacity);
        head = new ArrayNode(maxArraySize).asHead().withNext(new ArrayNode(maxArraySize).asTail());
        tail = head.nextArr.withPrev(head);
        arrCount = 2;
        eleCount = 0;
    }

    boolean availableSpaceForAppending() {
        return (tail.lastEmptyIndex < tail.elements.length - tail.reservedSpace);
    }

    boolean availableSpaceForInserting(ArrayNode a) {
        return (a.count < a.elements.length);
    }

    public boolean withinBounds(int index) {
        return index < eleCount || index >= 0;
    }

    void checkBound(int index) {
        if (!withinBounds(index)) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("the specified index exceeds"
                    + " the number of elements stored");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return eleCount;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return eleCount < 1;
    }

    void appendArrayBlock() {
        //make new arrayblock and make tail object point to it as next
        //while it will point to tail opject as previou
        tail.nextArr = new ArrayNode(maxArraySize).asTail().withPrev(tail);
        //increase array size by one
        arrCount++;
        //make the tail variable refer to the new arrayblock
        tail = tail.nextArr;
    }

    private void adjustCapacity() {
        if (eleCount > currCapacity) {
            currCapacity *= 10;
            maxArraySize = (int) Math.sqrt(currCapacity);
        } else if (eleCount > minCapacity && eleCount < currCapacity / 10) {
            currCapacity /= 10;
            maxArraySize = (int) Math.sqrt(currCapacity);
        }
    }

    private class ItemInf {

        E item;
        /**
         * index of item
         */
        int itemIndex;
        /**
         * ArrayNode that contain the item
         */
        ArrayNode itemArray = head;
        /**
         * index of the item in its containing array
         */
        int indexInArray;
        int beforeLength = 0; //total length of array blocks before current array

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private ItemInf getIndexInf(int index) {
        if (!withinBounds(index)) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("the specified index exceeds"
                    + " the number of elements stored");
        }
        ItemInf inf = new ItemInf();
        int beforeLength = 0;
        ArrayNode a = head;
        while (a != null) {
            if (index < beforeLength + a.count) {
                inf.itemArray = a;
                inf.itemIndex = index;
                inf.indexInArray = index - beforeLength + a.firstEmptyIndex + 1;
                inf.beforeLength = beforeLength;
                inf.item = (E) a.elements[inf.indexInArray];
                return inf;
            } else {
                beforeLength += a.count;
                a = a.nextArr;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private ItemInf getItemInf(Object o) {
        if(notHomogenous()){
            homogenize();
        }
        ItemInf inf = new ItemInf();
        int beforeLength = 0;
        ArrayNode a = head;
        while (a != null) {
            for (int i = a.firstEmptyIndex + 1; i < a.lastEmptyIndex; i++) {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                E e = (E) a.elements[i];
                if ((o == null && e == null) || (e != null && e.equals(o))) {
                    inf.itemArray = a;
                    inf.indexInArray = i;
                    inf.itemIndex = i + beforeLength;
                    inf.beforeLength = beforeLength;
                    inf.item = e;
                    return inf;
                }
            }
            beforeLength += a.count;
            a = a.nextArr;
        }
        return null;
    }

    void removeByInf(ItemInf inf) {
        ArrayNode a = inf.itemArray;
        int i = inf.indexInArray; // index of the element in the a.elements array
        System.arraycopy(a.elements, i + 1, a.elements, i, a.count - 1 - i);
        a.lastEmptyIndex--;
        a.count--;
        eleCount--;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return new LinkedArraysIterator();
    }

    public class LinkedArraysIterator implements Iterator<E> {

        /**
         * index of last returned item
         */
        int currIndex;
        /**
         * ArrayNode that contain the last returned item
         */
        ArrayNode currArray = head;
        /**
         * index of last returned item in its containing array
         */
        int indexInArray;
        int beforeLength = 0; //total length of array blocks before current array

        public LinkedArraysIterator() {
            currIndex = -1;
        }

        public LinkedArraysIterator(int start) {
            if (!withinBounds(start)) {
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("the specified index exceeds"
                        + " the number of elements stored");
            }
            if (start > 0) {
                ItemInf inf = getIndexInf(start - 1);
                currIndex = inf.itemIndex;
                currArray = inf.itemArray;
                indexInArray = inf.indexInArray;
                beforeLength = inf.beforeLength;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return currIndex + 1 < eleCount;
        }

        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public E next() {
            if (hasNext()) {
                currIndex++;
                if (currIndex < beforeLength + currArray.count) {
                    indexInArray = currIndex - beforeLength + currArray.firstEmptyIndex + 1;
                    return (E) currArray.elements[indexInArray];
                } else {
                    beforeLength += currArray.count;
                    currArray = currArray.nextArr;
                    indexInArray = currIndex - beforeLength + currArray.firstEmptyIndex + 1;
                    return (E) currArray.elements[indexInArray];
                }
            } else {
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("the specified index exceeds"
                        + " the number of elements stored");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            removeByInf(last());
            currIndex--;
            if (indexInArray - 1 > currArray.firstEmptyIndex) {
                indexInArray--;
            } else {
                currArray = currArray.prevArr;
                beforeLength -= currArray.count;
                indexInArray = currArray.lastEmptyIndex - 1;
            }
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ItemInf last() {
            ItemInf inf = new ItemInf();
            inf.itemIndex = currIndex;
            inf.itemArray = currArray;
            inf.indexInArray = indexInArray;
            inf.item = (E) inf.itemArray.elements[inf.indexInArray];
            inf.beforeLength = beforeLength;
            return inf;
        }

    }

    public void append(E item) {
        if (!availableSpaceForAppending()) {
            adjustCapacity();
            appendArrayBlock();
        }
        //add the element to the empty slot indicated by index
        tail.elements[tail.lastEmptyIndex] = item;
        //increase index by one to point again to empty slot
        tail.lastEmptyIndex++;
        //increase array element size by one
        tail.count++;
        //increase total element size by one
        eleCount++;
    }

    public void insert(E item, int index) {
        ItemInf inf = getIndexInf(index);
        ArrayNode a = inf.itemArray;
        if (!availableSpaceForInserting(inf.itemArray)) {
            adjustCapacity();
            a.expandTail();
        }
        int i = inf.indexInArray; // index of the element in the a.elements array
        if (a.lastEmptyIndex < a.elements.length) {//the available space are in tail of array
            System.arraycopy(a.elements, i, a.elements, i + 1, a.count - i + a.firstEmptyIndex + 1);
            a.elements[i] = item;
            a.lastEmptyIndex++;
        } else {//avaialable space are in head of array
            System.arraycopy(a.elements, a.firstEmptyIndex + 1, a.elements, a.firstEmptyIndex, i - (a.firstEmptyIndex + 1));
            a.elements[i - 1] = item;
            a.firstEmptyIndex--;
        }
        a.count++;
        eleCount++;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public E remove(int index) {
        ItemInf inf = getIndexInf(index);
        removeByInf(inf);
        return inf.item;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public E getByIndex(int index) {
        ItemInf inf = getIndexInf(index);
        return (E) inf.itemArray.elements[inf.indexInArray];
    }

    public int getIndexOf(E item) {
        ItemInf inf = getItemInf(item);
        if (inf != null) {
            return inf.itemIndex;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void homogenize() {
        //tester();
        adjustCapacity();
        LinkedArrays<E> newOne = new LinkedArrays<>(currCapacity);
        ArrayNode a = head;
        while (a != null) {
            newOne.appendRange((E[]) a.elements, a.firstEmptyIndex + 1, a.lastEmptyIndex - 1);
            a = a.nextArr;
        }
        currCapacity = newOne.currCapacity;
        head = newOne.head;
        tail = newOne.tail;
        arrCount = newOne.arrCount;
        maxArraySize = newOne.maxArraySize;
        eleCount = newOne.eleCount;
    }

    boolean notHomogenous() {
        int currentArraySize = (eleCount / arrCount);
        return currentArraySize < maxArraySize * 0.75 || currentArraySize > maxArraySize * 1.25;
    }



}
```

The full code prototype is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/ahmedMazherElKholy/AhmedLib/tree/master/src/ahmed/lib/utilities/datastructure).

Is this the best approach or is there an alternative?

Comment: Unfortunately your question is off-topic as of now, as the code to be reviewed must be [present in the question.](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1308) Code behind links is considered non-reviewable. Please add the code you want reviewed in your question. Thanks!

Comment: ok i will add it but it is lengthy

Comment: cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashed_array_tree. Don't link the chunks; have a directory - a separate array - of pointers to each chunk's start, for O(1) addressing. Without looking at your code, just from the diagram at the top, if you have to chase the sqrt(n) chunks, it's not O(1) but O(sqrt(n)) addressing. IOW, rather unacceptable. Also, personally, I much prefer not to resize the chunks, but to go with some constant, rather large chunk size. You can also have each chunk array to start and end at an offset, reserving some empty space, if you expect lots of insertions.

Comment: (the last suggestion will complicate the addressing though).

Comment: Nice idea but we will need to handle the growth of this backbone array beside this will require that the arrays be equal in size otherwise we will have to iterate through them  to calculate the desired index, also will need to rebuilding the entire data structure when it grow to maintain equal array size, i have abandoned this approach as it is complicated also it appeared to me after testing that indexing time of `LinkedArrays` near equal to `ArrayList` weird !  i didn't understand why

Answer (score 3):

#### Do you need to reinvent the wheel?

> ```
> class ArrayNode {
> ```

and

> ```
>     Object[] elements; // the array of elements
> ```

If I were doing this, I'd make it

```
class ArrayNode<T> implements List<T> {
```

and

```
    List<T> elements = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then you don't have to manage resizing manually and can get rid of the four `int` fields.

You can just pass through the `List` operations, as the `ArrayList` will know what to do with them.

But most importantly, this way you can have a normal generics implementation.  You don't need to play around with casting to and from `Object`.

#### Why not `List`?

> ```
> public class LinkedArrays<E> implements Collection<E> {
> ```

You have this implementing the `Collection` interface.  Why?  The operations that you are doing match the `List` interface.  Why not implement that?  You already have equivalents of most if not all of the required operations.

#### Why roll your own?

> ```
>     int arrCount;//current number of arrays
>     int maxArraySize;//maximum allowed size of array
>     ArrayNode head;//point to the head array
>     ArrayNode tail; //point to the tail array
> ```

Why not just do

```
    int maxArraySize;//maximum allowed size of array
    List<ArrayNode<E>> chunks = new LinkedList<>();
```

or even

```
    int maxArraySize;//maximum allowed size of array
    List<List<E>> chunks = new LinkedList<>();
```

Each chunk can be an `ArrayList` in the last version.

Then you can do the normal operations and don't have to implement your own.  You don't even need to implement `ArrayNode` if you don't want to do so.

#### Why \$\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n})\$?

You can implement a tree and get \$\mathcal{O}(\log n)\$ operations.  Asymptotically, logarithmic is better than the square root.

```
1     1  0
4     2  2
1024 32 10
```

It only gets worse from there.

Comment: "Do you need to reinvent the wheel?" i wanted to exercise my muscle ^_^ 
"Why not List?" i get tired at the end so i postponed this for a while
"You can implement a tree and get O(logn)" nice i will try it